# Is there a single CSS selector for all descendants of X and also X itself?

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I want to select an element with ID "Parent" *and* all of its descendants, I can do this:

```
#Parent, #Parent * { ... }
```

My question is: Is there a single selector that is equivalent to the above that doesn't require repeating `#Parent` twice?

In other words, is there a single selector that can select an element *and* all of its descendants at once?

---

Here is a snippet to play with, where `#left, #left *` and `#right, #right *` are the selectors of interest:

```css
#layout { display: flex; }
#layout > div { flex: 1 }
#layout * { border: 1px solid black; margin: 4px; padding: 4px; }

/* #left _and_ its descendants */
#left, #left * { border-color: #f0f; }

/* #right _and_ its descendants */
#right, #right * { border-color: #0ff; }
```

```html
<div id="layout">
  <div id="left">
    <div>test</div>
    <div><span>test</span><span>test</span></div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div>test</div>
    <div><span>test</span><span>test</span></div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: Is there a single selector that is equivalent to the
> above that doesn't require repeating `#Parent` twice?

No. There is not.

They are two different types of selectors, which is why they are defined separately in the spec.

One is a [simple selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#structure) (`#parent`).

The other is a [complex selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#structure) (`#Parent *`).

A combination of them both would require another type of selector, which doesn't exist [in the current version of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/).

Comment: This is partly incorrect. `#Parent *` does not meet the level 3 definition of a sequence of simple selectors which says "A sequence of simple selectors is a chain of simple selectors that are _not separated by a combinator_." The level 3 spec doesn't really have a name for a run of sequences of simple selectors separated by combinators which is what `#Parent *` actually is. The Level 4 spec calls it a [Complex selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#complex)

Comment: In addition a sequence of simple selectors is known in L4 as a compound selector.

Comment: Correct. I misread the spec. Answer revised. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only about color or the same property/value then use CSS variables:

```css
#layout { display: flex; }
#layout > div { flex: 1 }
#layout * { border: 1px solid var(--c,black); margin: 4px; padding: 4px; }

/* #left _and_ its descendants */
#left  { --c: #f0f; }

/* #right _and_ its descendants */
#right  { --c: #0ff; }
```

```html
<div id="layout">
  <div id="left">
    <div>test</div>
    <div><span>test</span><span>test</span></div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div>test</div>
    <div><span>test</span><span>test</span></div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```